# HTML image layout using PHP variable that is set dynamically with JavaScript [o r . . .]

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, viewport

Let "O" represent an image on an HTML page. Here is my HTML page on a screen size > X, where X is a certain number of pixels:

> OOOO
>
> OOOO
>
> OOOO

There are, say, 12 images; however, when viewed on a screen size ≤ X we should get:

> OO
>
> OO
>
> OO
>
> OO
>
> OO
>
> OO

The page uses PHP in the following way:

```
<?php
    $images = glob("images/*.jpg");
    foreach( $images as $image ){
        <!-- <img...width:25%;display:inline-block;.../> -->
    }
?>
```

I would like to make the "25" in this percent a variable dependent on whether the viewport is ≤ X or > X; say, w1 if > X and w2 if ≤ X. Is there a way to do this without using JavaScript? I will accept a JavaScript answer though.

---

"`...`" means there is more there, but I'm not showing it here.

Comment: Have you looked into CSS and vh/vw units? Or @media

Comment: When I do that and scale the browser width with my mouse the number of images per row remains constant. I want a set percent width which changes the number of images per row dynamically based on browser width.

Comment: Yeah, CSS can control image width / height

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS media queries to accomplish what you want:

```
/* default values */
img.class-name {
  width: 25%; /* whatever your default value is */
}

@media (min-width: YYpx) {
  img.class-name {
    width: 50%; /* value when the screen is at least YY px wide */
  }
}
```

Media queries are supported only in IE 9+

Answer (score 1):

Try using `css` `width` set to a minimum `px` or other unit value plus `15vw` to `25vw` depending on expected rendered scaling effect; setting `display` to `inline-block` , `height` to `25vh`

```
body {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding:4px;
}

img {
  display:inline-block;
  width:calc(50px + 15vw);
  height:25vh;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding:4px;
}
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wgjvq3b9/